# Why is $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$ homeomorphic to $S^2\times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$?

Tags: general-topology

One can define a quotient map $q:\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb{S}^2$ by $$q(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}.$$ But I don't understand why $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$?

Comment: It's the fact that polar coordinates are a parameterization of $\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Think about what the fibers of each $q(x)$ are - that is the sets of the form $\{x\in\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\}:f(x)=c\}$ for some $c\in\mathbb S^2$. Is there some way to parameterize the fibers (consistently) by $\mathbb R_{>0}$?

Comment: Just to be clear @Guiseppe Negro, you are referring to cylindrical coordinates (polar coordinates in 3-space)?

Comment: @crispypizza: No, not cylindrical but spherical coordinates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system (I wasn't notified because you misspelled my first name :-) )

Comment: Sorry about that @GiuseppeNegro. Thank you

Comment: Now I was notified. :-) you are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f:S^2\times \mathbb{R}_{>0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$ by $f(x,c)=cx$, it inverses is $x\rightarrow ({x\over{\|x\|}},\|x\|)$.